# How can i copy an object?

Tags: php

I'm really stuck with references in php. In my programm i've got something similiar to this:

1. Programm

   ```
   class Test
   {
       private $_property;

       function __construct($property)
       {
           $this->_property = $property;
       }

       public function setProperty($property)
       {
           $this->_property = $property;
       }

       public function getProperty()
       {
           return $this->_property;
       }
   }

   function doSmth(Test $var)
   {
       $newVar = new Test('test');

       //I need to do something here...
   }

   $var = new Test('original');

   doSmth($var);

   var_dump($var);
   ```
2. Question

What should i do to copy all contents of `$newVar` variable to my `$var` variable so that i will be able to see it after using `var_dump()` function that is outside of function `doSmth()`. And i can't use getters and setters in my programm because i've got a lot of them and it will be a lot of code. Is it possible to solve this problem with my limitations?

**UPDATE**: I can't return value in my function `doSmth()` and i also tried `__clone` but nothing works. Can someone show me how can i do it with `__clone()`?

Comment: Try looking for [__clone()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$newVar` only exists in the context of the function.

What you want to do is to create a return value like this:

```
function doSmth(Test $var)
{
    $newVar = new Test('test');

    //I need to do something here...

    return $newVar;
}
```

and call the function like this instead:

```
$myNewShinyVar=doSmth($var);
```

This way, your function returns the object of the class `Test` as a a return value.

```
var_dump($myNewShinyVar);
```

Edit: If you cannot return a value, you can pass by reference instead:

```
function doSmth(&$var)
{
    $var = new Test('test');
}
```

This will modify the variable itself that is passed as a parameter to it (rather than passing a copy of it)

```
doSmth($var);
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: why can't you? it is not said in the question.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention this.

Comment: Thanks your edits helped me. But i always thought that objects in php are copied by reference, correct me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to create a copy of object by using a *[clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)* keyword. It will help you to create full replica of source object. OR, what I think also might be useful for you, you can try to pass Test object by reference:

```
function doSmth(Test &$var)
{
    // Here you can do something with your var
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question a number of times I think is this what you are after:

```
function doSmth(Test $var)
{
  $newvar = clone $var;
  // do some stuff on a copy of $var, leaving $var intact
}

$var = new Test('original');

doSmth($var);

var_dump($var);
```